# I don't receive the call in my Springboot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying call to server in SpringBoot with multiples vars

From client , I send for URL 2 String and for post I send Array

```
const url: string = "http://localhost:8090/duplicateSession/" + currentExec + "/" + this.year;
   response = this.http.post<MyMessage>(url, arrayMonths, { responseType: 'json' });
```

Now I am trying get this ->

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/duplicateSession/{periodExec}/{periodYear}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public MyMessage duplicateSession(@RequestBody ArrayList<Integer> listPeriod, @PathVariable ("periodExec") String periodExec, @PathVariable ("periodYear") String periodYear) {
    System.out.println("hellooooo");
}
```

I tried with ->

```
const url: string = "http://localhost:8090/cm/duplicateSession?periodExec=" + currentExec + "&periodYear=" + this.year;
```

I dont'get error, I don't found error in Client, and I don't found error in my SpringBoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the format `?a=A&b=B` you are passing parameters to the url. Instead your url is specified as `/duplicateSession/{periodExec}/{periodYear}` and it is expecting path variables.

Comment: I tried with  /var/var and with  ?var=value&var=value. BUT nothing runs

Comment: Did you specify the `contextPath` variable in `applicaion.properties`?

Comment: I never had to do it

Comment: Aren't you forgetting `/cm` in the path after the port? In the js code is not there.

Comment: There is something that you are not saying to us

Comment: I am trying multiple vars -> "http://localhost:8090/cm/duplicateSession/" + currentExec + "/"
            + this.year + "/" + this.userParam.createUser; If I get 2-3 I can get 5-6 ...

Answer (score 1):

Need to subscribe to the http req in order to fire the event.

```
response = this.http.post<MyMessage>(url, arrayMonths, { responseType: 'json' });
response.subscribe((items) => console.log(items))
```